# Python Connection to Multiple Servers with Different SQL Dialects?

Tags: python, sql-server, teradata, pyodbc, connector

**Question**: How can I run SQL queries via Python to retrieve data from multiple servers that may have different SQL dialects (e.g. where one server dialect uses **TOP** X and another **SAMPLE** X)?

Currently I have some code that allows me to run a query against each server *separately* (which is insufficient):

```
    import pyodbc
    import pandas as pd
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=dsn_name;UID=username;PWD=password')
    query = str("""
                SELECT * 
                FROM sqlserver1.tableA 
                """)
    df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
```

**Goal**: What I would like to do is to join data from a different server, basically I would like to have an SQL query in Python that looks somewhat like this - handling different SQL dialects:

```
        query = str("""
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM sqlserver1.tableA as sq
                    INNER JOIN teradataserver2.tableB as tera
                            ON sq.id = tera.id
                    """)
```

.. P.S. I have tried a workaround like this:

```
        import pyodbc
        import pandas as pd
        cnxnServer1 = pyodbc.connect('DSN=dsn_name1;UID=username;PWD=password')
        cnxnServer2 = pyodbc.connect('DSN=dsn_name2;UID=username;PWD=password')

        queryServer1 = str("""
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM sqlserver1.tableA 
                    """)
        queryServer2 = str("""
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM teradataserver2.tableB 
                    """)
```

.. and then use a Pandas Merge. But **this is too ineffective**.

**Note**: I run Python 3.7

Comment: Did you try linked server which allow to execute the queries mentioned as your goal?

Comment: No, I have not. If that would achieve the goal, then I would be glad if you would share the solution.

Comment: What do you mean by *but this is too ineffective*? Slow? Errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd rather not (or are unable to) mess with server configurations (e.g., to create a linked server) then you might be able to do something with [SQLAlchemy's SQL Expression Language](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html) to create statements that are interpreted using the dialect of the SQLAlchemy `engine` object.

For example,

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

cnxn_url = 'mssql+pyodbc://@SQLmyDb'
engine = create_engine(cnxn_url)
metadata = MetaData()
my_table = Table('my_table', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
stmt = select([my_table.c.id, my_table.c.txt])\
    .select_from(my_table)\
    .order_by(my_table.c.id)\
    .limit(2)
with engine.begin() as conn:
    print(conn.execute(stmt).fetchall())
```

will send a T-SQL statement to the SQL Server and return the results.

If we simply change the connection URL to

```python
cnxn_url = 'mysql+pymysql://root:whatever@localhost/mydb'
```

then SQLAlchemy will send the appropriate MySQL statement to the MySQL server.

However, that may not be sufficient if you really want to join one table in database_A with another table in database_B. In that case you'd be looking at pulling the data from the various tables into a common environment like pandas DataFrames or tables in an in-memory SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine) to SQL Server for accessing `teradataserver2` from `sqlserver1`. The following query can be used in context of connection to `sqlserver1` (check name syntax for `teradataserver2`)

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA as sq
     INNER JOIN [teradataserver2].mydb.dbo.tableB as tera
         ON sq.id = tera.id
```